# Why does Record forget which arguments are implicit?

Tags: coq

It seems that when Record converts to Variant, it drops the data about which arguments are implicit.  Why?  Here is a MWE:

```
> Variant example {n : nat} (e : n=n) :=
 | a : nat -> example e.
> Check a.  
a
     : forall e : ?n = ?n, nat -> example e
where
?n : [ |- nat]
> Record example2 {n : nat} (e : n=n) := a2 { r: nat }.
> Check a2.
a2
     : forall (n : nat) (e : n = n), nat -> example2 e
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me... probably worth reporting it at https://github.com/coq/coq/issues.

Comment: Thanks, done! https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/14496#issue-919885251